# vga_switcheroo not in /sys/kernel/debug in 2.6.35-22 (kubuntu maverick)

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I have a sony VPCZ12 laptop. It has those dual video cards that are a pain to get working in linux. The new 2.6.35 kernel is supposed to support that with the vga_switcheroo module which is supposed to be located in /sys/kernel/debug on >2.6.35.

The problem is that when I boot my laptop, it freezes at a blackscreen unless I boot with options `i915.nomodeset=0`. It won't boot into X, but I can get to a terminal which is fine. But then vga_switcheroo isn't in `/sys/kernel/debug`.

Is this a ubuntu bug on how the kernel is compiled? Or is it because I have to boot with `i915.nomodeset`?

The livecd boots into X just fine, but I've never found a way to get X working on the installation. There's a lot of information about linux on the z12 but most of it is either outdated, doesn't work, or just plain doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a kernel with vga_switcheroo enabled and KMS, i.e. kernel mode setting, active (which you haven't as you boot with nomodeset).

To check if vga_switcheroo is enabled in the kernel, have a look into the Ubuntu config of your kernel. You should find it in /boot with a name along the lines of /boot/config-2.6.35-XX-generic with XX some number corresponding to your kernel.

If it is not enabled, you find a custom Ubuntu kernel with vga_switcheroo enabled at http://www.ramoonus.nl/2010/08/linux-kernel-2-6-35-installation-guide-for-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: vga_switcheroo is enabled in the kernel, but it's still not in /sys/kernel/debug

Comment: Kernel mode setting seems to be a requirement for vga_switcheroo to work. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I never got it working in Ubuntu, but I got a working KDE system using arch. So I'll post an answer here in case anyone else comes here for the same problem.

I could never get it working in Ubuntu. I couldn't boot without `i915.modeset=0` and without that vgaswitcheroo doesn't show up.

What I ended up doing was installing arch, then before doing any setup in my new arch install, I installed a vanilla 2.6.35.7 kernel from kernel.org. That booted to a terminal just fine and I'm up and running on KDE.

Comment: The problem with Ubuntu might be with Grub 2. If you google for Ubuntu and your Laptop, you'll find reports that reverting Grub 0.97 allows booting with KMS enabled. I guess Arch still uses Grub 0.97?

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in ubuntu patches to kernel. Try a vanilla kernel or another distro.

@fschmitt no it's not grub2, i'm using it on arch with KMS and vgaswitcheroo